# ssh - public key in authorized server, but still asking for password

Tags: ssh

I did `ssh-copy-id` to copy my public key to the remote server.

On the remote server, I see my public key in `authorized_keys`.

I've restarted `sshd`.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa aleph@132.209.211.2
```

Why is it still asking for the password ?

It works if I set permissions to the home directoy, from 777 to 700 :

```
chmod 700 $HOME
```

But that's not good.

I really need 777 on my home directory.

How can I make ssh work, with all permissions (777) on remote home directory ?

Comment: What's in the server's logs when you try to connect?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set permissions to the home directoy, from 777 to 700 :

```
chmod 755 $HOME
```

755 is alright for me.   700 was too restrictive.